# Receive mail from Paypal only to paypal@domain.com

Tags: postfix, email-server

My postfix server accepts emails for 11 domains. I have paypal@xxxxxx.com email accounts on 2 of those domains. I would like to only have Paypal be able to send me emails to these accounts. So if joe@ccccccc.com sends me an email, I would like postfix to properly send it to /dev/null without it telling joe@ccccccc.com that his email was properly disposed of.

Comment: How do you plan to recognize which mail is "from PayPal"? Have they stopped sending messages from *security@totally-not-phishing-paypal.com*?

Comment: @anx The only email I receive on those accounts from PayPal has a PayPal dot com domain. Then there is the junk that I don't want need to stay on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**Postfix [lookups may be nested](https://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html), so you can first filter out the special-treatment receiving *recipients*, then selectively reject unexpected *senders* just for those.**

Put a per-recipient lookup into a suitable restriction class. Typically `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` in `main.cf´, but if you use some form of *whitelisting* there you would have to think about the order, otherwise an override meant for other purposes might override the "only ACME" restriction too.

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 [..]
 reject_non_fqdn_recipients
 check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/access_recipient.pcre
 [..]
```

In that lookup `/etc/postfix/access_recipient.pcre`, define which recipients need special treatment:

```
/^acme@(onedomain|otherdomain)\.example$/   smtpd_restriction_sender_acme
```

The create that new lookup back in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_restriction_classes =
  smtpd_restriction_sender_acme
  [..]
smtpd_restriction_sender_acme =
  check_sender_access pcre:/etc/postfix/maps/access_sender_acme.pcre
```

In that lookup `/etc/postfix/access_sender_acme.pcre`, define which senders are treated normally, and what to do about the rest:

```
/@acme\.example$/              DUNNO
/./                            REJECT 5.7.0 Recipient is for ACME only
```

---

Cross-check:

1. My answer works for the non-existing unicorn company ACME Inc which promises to never send legitimate mail from envelope senders other than `*@acme.example`.

   This is not promised for PayPal, who instead of permanently discontinuing messages sent from their not publicly enumerated alternate domains, [tell you](https://www.paypal.com/us/security/learn-about-fake-messages) to recognize phishing by the way that phishers might not spell out your *full name*. If PayPal sends you important, legitimate messages from other domains, you will not receive them.
2. The entire solution is fairly useless if you are not also rejecting messages *claiming* to be from PayPal but failing to provide verifiable proof they really are. I recommend a *DMARC* milter set to reject failing messages.
3. Surely you *could* also use `DISCARD` in place of `DEFER` or `REJECT` as I suggested, but that just means your setup is more annoying to diagnose should your selection criteria ever stop recognizing all the wanted mail, and additionally means you have to first receive the full mail, before recognizing it will not be delivered anyway.

Comment: So much for me cutting the lawn tonight. Let me digest this routine and I'll post my findings.